# stripe get full usage history

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm looking for a way to get the full usage history of every billing period,
I managed to get period-usage-history using `stripe.SubscriptionItem.list_usage_record_summaries`
but I want to get the detailed list of usage for every period.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. Generally Stripe recommend that you persist usage records in your own database.

Comment: @JonathanSteele clear, thank you for your response